# How to solve $\text{ constant} = \sin(2*\theta)\;?$

Tags: trigonometry

> What would you do to solve $0.587 = \sin(2\theta)$?

I know that this question is rather basic, but I've had no luck trying to find answers online.  I was wondering if $\sin$ could be replaced by $\text{opposite} \over \text{hypotenuse}$, but I'm not exactly sure how that would work.

Comment: Dumb question, didn't know a lot of things back when I wrote it, including how to search Google for math. Closing as off-topic is a cancer, though. "put on hold as too basic" (easily researched, or lacking minimum bar of understanding) or "put on hold as missing information or ad-hoc" (question lacks enough info to make it broadly useful to the community) would both be useful alternatives across SE. Or something like that. There's probably a meta about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We take the inverse $\sin$ of each side of your equation:

$$0.587 = \sin(2\theta) \implies \sin^{-1}(0.587) = \sin^{-1}(\sin(2\theta)) = 2 \theta $$ $$\iff \theta  \frac{\sin^{-1}(0.587)}{2}$$

Comment: That's nice to know.  I actually thought there was no answer because of Yahoo's answers for similar problems (thanks a million, uninformed Yahoo answerers).  I haven't learned inverse $\sin$, $\cos$, etc. yet.

Comment: @amWhy: At this rate, you'll reach your goal by TG! :-) +1